# How to escape single quotes in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript, escaping, backslash

I have a user supplied text and I need to prepend all backslashes and single quotes with a backslash. How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var string:String = "something 'is' \\fishy here";
trace(string);//something 'is' \fishy here
string = string.replace(/(['\\])/g, "\\$1");
trace(string);//something \'is\' \\fishy here
```

Answer (score 2):

Amarghosh's answer is spot on. If you want an easy way to test out AS3 regex, [Grant Skinner's Regexr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/desktop/) is awesome.